# Maximium value for AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: html, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, ascx

I have a AutoCompleteExtender with the following code:

```
 <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" ID="autoCompleteOrigem" TargetControlID="txtClienteOrigem"
                            ServicePath="~/Cliente/AutoCompleteCliSubCli/HandlerCliente.asmx" ServiceMethod="RetornaClientePesquisaOrigem"
                            MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="20"
                            OnClientPopulating="autoCompleteOrigem_OnClientPopulated" CompletionListCssClass="AutoExtender"
                            CompletionListItemCssClass="AutoExtenderList" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="AutoExtenderHighlight"
                            CompletionListElementID="listPlacement" OnClientItemSelected="SetSelectedValueOrigem">
                        </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

I have a problem, with this it only shows 5 lines with a scroll bar.Like the image.

[image]

I need to change this to show 20 but i couln'd find the property to change.Someone knows if is it possible with this component?

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the height of the popup using the `height` CSS attribute of `CompletionListCssClass`.

In your case it will look like this:

```
.AutoExtender {
    height: 200px;
}
```